# Header unset Server not working for static files

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I'm trying to  unset the "Server" field in response headers. I do this using `Header unset Server`, and that works fine for requests handled by mod_perl. However, for requests to `/static` I use Apache to serve static files. For some reason, when these files are loaded directly in the browser, the `Server` field is not removed. How can I go about fixing this?

Relevent parts of my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
Header unset Server

<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Location />
        SetHandler modperl
        PerlResponseHandler MyHandler
    </Location>

    Alias /static/ /home/site/static/

    <Location /static>
        SetHandler None
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the server token off in the header does not appear to be an option for static content.  You can reduce then disclosure to `apache` using the `ServerTokens` option.  You can minimize disclosure by adding the following lines to your configuration.  Reload the configuration after making the change.

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```